# Update tableview with new elements in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, rss

So I have this chunk of code in numberOfRowsInSection to change how many is shown based on what sidebar option is pressed (A different tableView). When the user selects the index #1 they should only seen the amount of rows that are present in the fetch request. Nothing will update when I change the index and I am guessing that is because it is not being refreshed/updated. What code should I use to update this correctly and where should it be placed?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if sidebarindex == 3{
    return feeds.count
    } else if sidebarindex == 2{
    return feeds.count
    } else if sidebarindex == 1{

        let moc = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()
        var favNames: [String] = []
        let fetchRequestM = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Favorite")
        if let favs = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestM, error: nil) as? [Favorite] {
            favNames = favs.map { $0.favoriteTitle }}

        if favNames.count != 0{
            return favNames.count
        }else{
            return 1
        }

    } else{
    return feeds.count
    }



}
```

Comment: Is sidebar option on same UIViewController or different UIViewController. If it is same UIViewController then you can just table reloadData if it is different UIViewController then you would have to use delegate and protocol to update tableview

Answer (score 1):

Note: Beginner at IOS and Swift, so please tell me if I'm wrong. But this is my attempt at answering your question:

The code used to refresh the data in a tableView would be:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Without seeing the code I can't say exactly where to place it, but an educated guess would be to place it in the function that gets activated when the side bar item is pressed. Example:

```
@IBAction func sideBarItem1Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // Set the index here
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you update your post with your code I may be able to determine where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4

```
func reloadTableData(){

   self.tableMyList.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: if tableView.tag == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableCell") as! MainTableCell
            cell.tableInner.tag = indexPath.row + 1
            cell.tableInner.delegate = self
            cell.tableInner.dataSource = self
            cell.tableInner.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondTableCell") as! SecondTableCell
            cell.lblBool.text = "True"
            return cell}